# Angular 2 - injecting service into a component that the service created

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a service, something like this:

```
constructor(private containerRef: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: ComponentResolver) {}

create(options: any) {
    this.resolver.resolveComponent(TestComponent)
        .then((factory: ComponentFactory<TestComponent>) => {
            let ref = this.containerRef.createComponent(factory);
        });
}
```

This creates a `TestComponent`, all good. My problem comes, when I try to inject the same service into this component.

```
constructor(private service: RandomService) { ... }
```

And here I get an exception: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null`.

I can inject any other service into the component, just not this one that created it. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Seems you didn't provide `RandomService`

Comment: I did that, but nothing changed. For now I added `ref.instance.service = this` after creating the component and it seems to work, but I'm not actually sure whether it's a proper way, is it?